# Sqlite ROW_NUMBER not working in react-native-sqlite-storage

Tags: sqlite, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

Here is my query.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RANDOM()) AS rowNo, id, name, address FROM Users
```

It works in Sqlite Db Browser.
Is there any other way to put rowNo on randomize rows?

My Users table

```
id | integer, auto-increment
name | text
address | text
```

Comment: welcome ...add your db structure and script with error .

Comment: I found out that Windows Functions requires SQLite 3.25.0 or greater but sqlite bundled with api 28 is 3.19. I solved this by using sqlite included in react-native-sqlite-storage module.